# UIButton colors have gradient in iphone 8 plus and iphone X (iOS version independent issue)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have used simple UIButton with my usecase being: 3 different background colors for states - Normal, Highlighted and Disabled. I have achieved this by the following code:

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!{
    didSet{
        myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3803921569, blue: 0.6196078431, alpha: 1)), for: .normal)
        myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4745098039, blue: 0.7725490196, alpha: 1)), for: .highlighted)
        myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .gray), for: .disabled)
    }
}
```

Extension function for UIImage---

```
class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```

But my button appears as follows in iphone8 and iphone X

[image]

Instead of gray, it is giving me a gradient of gray and blue

Comment: So, do you want to let it be a solid gray color?

Comment: Btw, I tried to `myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .gray), for: .disabled)` it does not compile (Type 'UIImage' has no member 'imageWithColor').

Comment: @AhmadF I want a solid gray color. This is swift 3 that i have used.

Comment: `imageWithColor` is not a built-in member of `UIImage`, but it's a common extension added by util libraries. Please tell us were this code comes from (i.e. what lib you use).

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I have faced with this issue too, using exactly the same code. Solution was pretty simple: in your extension, change CGRect height value to 1.0 instead of 0.5. Now, everything will be rendered properly on every device. Strange issue, maybe somebody has ideas, why it works that way?

Your updated extension code:

```
class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func addGradientToBackground() {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.frame.size)
        layer.colors = [color1, color2, color3]
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
     }
```

Instead of color1, color2, color3 you can add your color respectively.

Comment: I don't want the gradient. I want solid colours for 3 button states and Im getting that gradient instead only on iphone 8 plus and iphoneX. It is working fine in other phones.

Comment: Have you try it to put that code of line in main thread, I means that right that line in DispatchQueue.main.asyn{}

Answer (score 0):

If you aiming to let the button to has a solid background color, you would need to change:

```
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .gray), for: .disabled)
```

<sub>Note that this line of code doesn't compile for me.</sub>

to:

```
myButton.backgroundColor = .gray
```

There is no need to set a background image for the button in your case, instead you should change directly the button background color (solid).